# Unclear on making an API call

Tags: api, powershell, egnyte

I am looking for some help with how to use the Egnyte API to make a call using PowerShells invoke-restmethod to list files/folders - https://developers.egnyte.com/docs/read/File_System_Management_API_Documentation#List-File-or-Folder

From their documentation I must first get a oauth2 token which I am unsure how to do so and then authenticate and make the call.

I've come up with the following below however I'm not sure how to proceed...

```
#credentials
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$apikey = "api-key"
$token = "token"

#auth to Egnyte
-Username $username -Password $password -AccessKey $apikey -token $token

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://EgnyteDomain.egnyte.com/pubapi/v1/fs/
```

Comment: The oauth2 secret should be available from your account page. REST implies no state, which means that token should be passed every request.  Based on their cURL example, you would pass this as a header: `-Headers @{Authorization = 'Bearer OAUTH2TOKENHERE'}`

Comment: [Here's the doc on authentication](https://developers.egnyte.com/docs/read/Public_API_Authentication)